# Inheritance with Java and Hibernate - Typecasting on updates

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, constructor

I have the following hierarchy in my classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Parent")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Parent {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorVlaue("FirstChild")
public class FirstChild extends Parent {
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorVlaue("SecondChild")
public class SecondChild extends Parent {
}
```

This creates a table Parent as expected.

Some business logic in my app:

As the request is accepted , it is persisted as "Parent" type and creates the following entry in the table

```
Dtype    id  value
Parent   1   "some value"
```

As the request is processed it could either be of type `FirstChild` or of type `SecondChild`  so in my code somewhere I have

```
if (some condition is met) {
// change the Parent to its firstChild type
}
else {
// chnage it to "SecondChild" type
}
```

Is my understanding and usage of inheritance correct? I am essentially downcasting objects in the if loop which throw runtime exceptions, but does changing the type of an object also change the `DTYPE` value in the database? I am essentially using inheritance to keep things organized as their types. Is there some magic I can do in the constructors to achieve this? But the real question is is the `Dtype` modifiable on an update?

To work with this further,

I created contsructors in the child classes as

```
public FirstChild(Parent parent) {
id = parent.id
}
```

but this creates a new row for the sub types ,

```
  Dtype       id  value
  Parent      1   "some value"
  FirstChild  2   "some value"
```

I am making sure that the "firstChild" record is created with the parent ID (1) but I am not sure why a second row is created

Comment: sorry that was a copy paste error, I do have the DiscriminatorColumn as expected , I am just interested in changing the type on updates

Comment: You can't, just like you can't change the type of an object in Java. You should probably use a has-a association rather than a is-a.

Comment: So what value is inheritance with hibernate? It makes perfect sense within Java objects

Comment: When you write `// change the Parent to its firstChild type`, what does it mean? How is your code look like?

Answer (score 3):

There is not a real inheritance in relational databases. Hibernate is just simulating it. Inheritance is a programming concept to use other classes like an owner. But you can't use other table as owning table.. In an child table if you have an element than you have a parent but where is the parent ? Parent is an element too.. ( a row of data ). So you simulate it in databases.
Hibernate has some inheritance strategies.'SINGLE_TABLE' is one of them and collects parent table and child tables in 1 table. To differantiate which type is which class uses 'DiscriminatorColumn' on database. This column cant be changed it is static and declared with your java class. You can use 'DiscriminatorValue' to select a value to identify a java class at 'DiscriminatorColumn'. 
So your inheritance understanding is differs on relational databases. You must declare every child row data on parent table rows...

Answer (score 1):

> But the real question is is the Dtype modifiable on an update?

No, you cant: [source](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-discriminator).

From your example your pure java code would look like this:

```
Parent parent = new Parent(); //object received from request, stored in database as it is
if (some conditions is met) {
   // FirstChild firstChild = (Parent) parent; //this would throw ClassCastException
   FirstChild firstChild = new FirstChild(parent); //creating new object, gc will collect parent
}
```

So hibernate act same way as java: you cannot update `Parent`, you have to create new record for `firstChild` and delete `parent`.

Wouldn't be helpfull for you use `@DiscriminatorFormula` instead of checking `some condition is met` when processing the request?

```
@DiscriminatorFormula("case when value = 'some value' then 'FirstChild' else 'SecondChild' end")
```

Then you wouldnt have to save `Parent` and then process its records.

Answer (score 1):

These are my findings:

1. There is no objective reason why a **`Child`** should extend **`Parent`**. In terms of modeling I would have instead one abstract class lets call it **`FamilyMember`** and then **`Parent`**, **`FirstBorn`** and **`SecondBorn`** would extend from the family member.
2. The downcasting problem would be solved by (1)
3. Hibernate does not support update of discriminator value. This mean that if a child comes to age and is no longer a child , but a parent. The child record needs to be deleted and a new record corresponding to a Parent be created. This is how it works. A child is a child until it is no longer a child and then the child record gets deleted and a new one not child gets created.